# XML - convert to JSON, make array and maintain the order of items

Tags: xml, json

I have a following XML, which I would like to convert to JSON, but maintain the order of items. I am currently using [X2JS](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/).

```
<array_like_item>
    <item_type_1 some_attr="data123" another_attr="data123" />
    <item_type_2 some_attr="data456" another_attr="data456" />
    <item_type_1 some_attr="data789" another_attr="data789" />
</array_like_item>
```

what I am getting know:

```
{
    "array_like_item": {
        "item_type_1": [
            {"_some_attr":"data123","_another_attr":"data123"},
            {"_some_attr":"data789","_another_attr":"data789"}
        ],
        "item_type_2": {
            "_some_attr":"data456","_another_attr":"data456"
        }
    }
}
```

what I would like to get (order is important):

```
{
    "array_like_item": [
        { 
            "item_type_1": { "_some_attr":"data123", "_another_attr":"data123"}
        },
        { 
            "item_type_2": { "_some_attr":"data456", "_another_attr":"data456"}
        },
        { 
            "item_type_1": { "_some_attr":"data789", "_another_attr":"data789"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.